# How to block a user from accessing SharePoint that's on a group with permissions to access

Tags: active-directory, permissions, sharepoint

Example:

I added to Readers my 'DOMAIN\domain users' on SharePoint. I want to prevent user JOHN to access my SharePoint site, is there any way of doing that in SharePoint, without going into AD? Like creating a no access permission and add that user with that permission?  I have tried that but didn't work, any ideas or workarounds? Is it possible? I understand this isn't a good practice, but... :)

Hope you have understand my question, Tks.
Pedro

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint uses the least restricctive at the collection level so you can prevent access entirely by goin into your central admin and changing the policy to deny all on the particular user.

At the collection level though, you'd have to apply more specific permissions or change AD to get what you're looking for.